# Parsing nested curly brace with php regex

Tags: php, arrays, regex, multidimensional-array

I want to parse raw string with nested curly braces to multidimensional arrays. Below I added sample code which works. But main problem my regex captures only first matched group and ignores another occurences.

Any help highly appreciated.

Code:

```
$regex = '/(?ims)(group [a-z0-9\s\,\.\:#_\-@]+)\{([^\}]*)\}/';
preg_match_all( $regex, file_get_contents('data.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH), $arr); 
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arr[0] as $i => $x)
    {
        $selector = trim($arr[1][$i]);
        $rules = explode(';', trim($arr[2][$i]));
        $result[$selector] = array();
        foreach ($rules as $strRule)
        {
            if (!empty($strRule))
            {
                $rule = explode(" = ", $strRule);
                $result[$selector][][trim($rule[0])] = trim($rule[1]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Raw string (data.txt):

```
group A { T1 { X = 44; }
          T2 { Y = 33; } }

group B { T1 { X = 555; } }
```

Code Output:

```
Array (
    [group A] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [T1 { X] => 44 
        ) 
    )
    [group B] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [T1 { X] => 555 
        ) 
    )
)
```

But excepted Output:

```
Array(
    [group A] => Array(
        [T1] => Array(
            [X] => 44
        ) 
        [T2] => Array (
            [Y] => 33
        )
    )
    [group B] => Array(
        [T1] => Array(
            [X] => 555
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you share your expected output for this raw string `group A { T1 { X = 44; } T2 { Y = 33; } }`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preg\_match\_all only returns first match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655374/preg-match-all-only-returns-first-match)

Comment: Array ([group A] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [T1 { X] => 44 )[1] => Array ( [T2 { Y] => 33) )[group B] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [T1 { X] => 555 ) ) )

Comment: Why are there curly braces in the output? Are you sure that's really the output?

Comment: Because thins regex pattern does not parse nested braces in string as well. That is the problem.

Comment: Regex just doesn't work that way. You can only retrieve the last data a capturing group matched. … so first match the groups in one regex and then match the contents in another regex for each group in a loop.

Comment: I changed pattern little bit and now it parses nested brackets. But need catch keywords also.

Please check here: [example](https://regex101.com/r/JT40HO/1)

I except output like this:
`Array
(
    [group A] => Array
        (
            [T1] => Array
                (
                    [X] => 44
                )

            [T2] => Array
                (
                    [Y] => 33
                )

        )

)`

Answer (score 1):

A better solutions might exists, but it works.

Ensure your input cannot have deeper values, or you have to improve/rewrite the entiere rule !

```
$input = <<<REG
group A { T1 { X = 44; }
          T2 { Y = 33; } }

group B { T1 { X = 555; } }
REG;

$out   = [];
$cbuff = null;
$rule  = "/^(?<group>[^\{\}]*)?\{|((?<set>[\w\s]+)\{(?<var>[\w\s]+)=(?<val>[\d\s]+)[;\s]+\})/im";
preg_replace_callback($rule, function($m)
use(&$out, &$cbuff) // import locally our working requirements
{
    $m = array_filter($m, "is_string", ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY); // cleaning
    $m = array_map("trim", array_filter($m)); // cleaning and trim

    if(key($m)=="group") // get & create the current root group
        $out[($cbuff = reset($m))] = [];

    if(isset($m["var"])) // assuming 'var' exists, you'll get 'set/var' too
    {
        if(is_null($cbuff)) return; // prevent no group found
        $out[$cbuff][$m["set"]] = [$m["var"] => $m["val"]];
    }
}, $input);

var_dump($out);
```

Will output:

```
array(2) {
  ["group A"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["T1"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["X"]=>
      string(2) "44"
    }
    ["T2"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Y"]=>
      string(2) "33"
    }
  }
  ["group B"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["T1"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["X"]=>
      string(3) "555"
    }
  }
}
```

## Hint

I think you are ok with PHP,
but i put a little bit of explaination about regexes:

first i've used "named group" for each parts 'set/var/val' pattern: `?<name>`

That confer an own group key under the matching output

`(?<set>...)|(?<var>...)` gives --> `["set" => ...], ["var" => "..."]`

Finally, to separate the sub properties to root group,
i'm just matching any part does not contains brackets

## Bench

You can retrive my bench on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XMZpMU/1)

```
3 matches, 60 steps (~0ms)
5 matches, 107 steps (~0ms)
```

yes it can be optimized!